# What's my chances of recuperating taxes withheld on my Royal Bank of Canada shares if I'm not a resident of Canada?

Tags: taxes, canada, non-resident, refund

For a couple years now, RBC has been wihholding Canadian taxes from my dividend payouts. I'm not a resident of Canada nor own any property in Canada - I've inherited their shares because they bought a bank in my country of which I owned shares.  Can I get this money back?  It is a couple hundred a year in withholdings but it adds up over time!

Comment: As God replied to a man who asked on his daily prayers each day that God would make him a lottery winner "Meet me halfway: buy a lottery ticket!"  Analogously, file a (non-resident) Canadian income tax return: you might well be entitled to a full return of taxes withheld.